# iOS VPN will NOT connect on certain WiFi

Tags: ios, vpn

I have downloaded a VPN service app, and it works fine. However, if I run on school WiFi, VPN hangs on "Connecting..." and after 10 seconds it disconnects and tries again. I believe this is a WiFi problem, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 7):

Most schools have firewalls on their network that prevent VPNs from being used. This is because firewall website filtering can be usually bypassed by using a VPN.

So as you guessed, it is something on the network that’s blocking the VPN.

And just so you know I have not found a way to bypass a VPN blocker or firewall(I am also a student at a school with a similar firewall)

Comment: Not just bypassing web filtering, VPNs are notoriously bandwidth hungry and will gobble up bandwidth even when usage is minimal.

Comment: @Allan Does it do this just because the encrypted traffic is bigger then the unencrypted? Or is there another reason?

Comment: That's just one.  Another is that it must create a static tunnel (both end points must be active) so there needs to be continual traffic in both directions to keep it connected.

Comment: So in other words, I'm screwed. Correct?

Comment: Try using the Tor web browser. I think I might have used that while my school was doing VPN blocking @Unknown

Comment: The problem is that it's a game that connects, so I need it to be more than a browser

Comment: @Unknown There’s ways to route compute traffic to Tor. I think you need to set the socks proxy in network preferences to either localhost:9150 or localhost:9151. I forget which one. The only thing is that Tor isn’t known for being fast, so online gaming could be laggy.

Comment: It is fairly easy to bypass such blocks - usually running the VPN on port 443 (making it look like SSL on the web) is enough. If not, an SSL tunnel almost certainly will be. [See this article](https://www.bestvpn.com/how-to-hide-openvpn-traffic-an-introduction/). The latter does of course assume that you control the VPN server.

Comment: @Birjolaxew that doesn’t work with all VPN blockers. For example mine blocks all encrypted traffic that doesn’t use a preshared key. An example of something that used s preshared key is SSL. That’s also why changing it to port 443 won’t make it look like SSL as VPN don’t use pre shared keys.

Comment: Allan's information is largely incorrect. While there is some very small fixed overhead for a VPN, there is no degree of "continual traffic" while idle that would impact other network users. Filtering is purely because whoever put the filter in place wants control over what you can access and ability to intercept your communications and authentication channels. It is not about resource usage.

Comment: OP, if you need advice on VPN-blocking bypass or on the dangers of using this network without VPN, you should probably ask on another SE site like security.SE, since the topic is not Apple-specific and the people who could best help are unlikely to be reading here.

Comment: @MatthewN SSL is just a protocol. Preshared keys are rarely, if ever, used nowadays - and certainly not for HTTPS (which I assume is what you're referring to). In general, if you can connect to websites using HTTPS, then you can hide your OpenVPN connection.

Comment: On IOS, how would I forward TOR vpn to ssl?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Psiphon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/psiphon/id1276263909?ls=1&mt=8), it is a vpn designed to bypass firewalls. It works at my school.